# Re-Calculating Rows in File GDB Feature Classes

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I run the script that I created below, but when it is completed and I check the FC tables, nothing has changed.

The script iterates through each feature class of a database and then iterates through each row of that feature class to check if the first 4 characters of the string record under the field "Photo1" are eqaul to "http". If the characters are "http", then it rewrites the field with the new given path. In other word, if there is already a web link, it rewrites it. This is because some rows do not have links in them.

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

parish = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
field = 'Photo1'
path = r"http://website.ca.gov/Photos"


for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
    for row in rows:
        photolink = str(row.getValue(field))

        if photolink[0][:4] == "http": 

            photolinkMod = photolink.split(r'/')
            photo = len(photolinkMod) - 1

            row.setValue(field, os.path.join(path, parish, photo))
            rows.updateRow(row)

del row, rows
```

Comment: I think you do not need the brackets here on your photolink varable, if photolink[0][:4] == "http": TRY if photolink[:4] == "http":.  The new da.cursor in v10.1 and greater uses bracket indexes to relate to defined field(s).

Comment: @artwork21. Should move that into an answer. @TacoB0t's `if` statement will never be true.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need the [0] brackets here on this statement:

`if photolink[0][:4] == "http":`

That would return "h" only and not "http"

TRY

`if photolink[:4] == "http":`

The new arcpy.da.UpdateCursor in v10.1 and greater uses bracket indexes to relate to defined field(s) and also is faster since it does not iterate over each fc field.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, field) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        value = row[0]
        if value[:4] == "http":
            # continue on with logic
```